# Alfresco doesn't start in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, alfresco

I'm new with alfresco, i'm trying to run it but i have one problem. In tomcat in the manager app page i have my alfresco application but not running (running = false). If i try to start tomcat return me error

"FAIL - Application at context path /alfresco could not be started"

I use kubuntu 11.10, tomcat 7 and alfresco 4

someone can help me?

here is catalina log http://pastebin.com/NEPfRt8B

EDIT:

after adding postgree drivers to lib dir

http://pastebin.com/EzkpZPyE

EDIT2:

Thank you all guys! I've done it.

For others users with same errors i suggest to use java-openjdk instead java-sun

@drndivoje yes, it gives me that error because of a java process in background, i need to stop it while installing any time i want to restart tomcat server.

Comment: please paste the content of `$TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out`, there's little to tell without some more details

Comment: it's very long, where can i put it?

Comment: @user1427054 your log covers a period of 3 hours. It will be easier if you select just the relevant time window.

Comment: oh i'm sorry. I updated it with last attempt

Comment: You might be missing the Postgress jdbc driver.

Comment: I do it, but seems others errors occur, i've load another error paste

Comment: Now you seem to have a port conflict. Try to kill all java processes and then restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'*

Probably means you're missing the Postgress JDBC driver in the lib subdir of Tomcat.

If you haven't done so yet, follow [these](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/postgresql-config.html) instructions on how to configure Alfresco 4 with PostgreSQL

Comment: it gives errors anyway, but i think not on postgress driver now, i updated my post with another pastebin

Answer (score 3):

Alfresco uses port 50500 for RMI. That port is already in use on your box. You can easyly change RMI port number following instruction from Alfresco wiki http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Port_numbers

The second solution is to kill that process manually (it is not recommended for production boxes, but for local dev environment it is much more easy to do).
Use: `netstat -tulpn | grep 50500`to find process  running on 50500 port. If it is RMI (probably not killed after last alfresco restart on your machine), fire : `kill <pid>`.

Hope it will work for you.